# Netbeans PHP debugging when called from a VB.NET app

Tags: php, vb.net, netbeans, xdebug

I have a Netbeans setup for a PHP API, with debugging (all works OK), and configured to debug calls with standard browser Firefox. This is all fine.

We have a VB.NET application which makes calls to this (development) API from the same machine: is there any way I can configure Netbeans to capture a request made from this application, in the same way it captures requests made direct from the browser?

The PHP application sits on a WAMP server stack.

This would aid debugging the VB.NET application hugely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way and it's pretty simple.

Just set the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` GET or POST variable to the value of your [`idekey` configuration variable](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#idekey). So it may look like this (in the case of GET variable):

```
http://example.com?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=idekey
```

Or you can also send a cookie together with the request with the value `XDEBUG_SESSION=idekey`, which is, in fact, what's done automatically when you use the previous way of GET/POST variable.

Check the [Xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session) for details.

Comment: Oh you clever, clever person. Thank you very much indeed.